# AdMob and "older" devices

Tags: android, admob

Right, when using the admob sdk, I am aware that I need to link against android-13 or higher, but this is a little annoying to me.

If I'm developing a app for 2.2+ I don't really want eclipse to show me unsupported features of classes in its code completion suggestions.

Currently, as a work around, I'll develop linking against the actual target sdk, and then before a deploy change to a never version to allow AdMobile to run. So basically, my main branch is setup for 4.0.3, and my development branch is setup for 2.2. When I am ready to deploy, I merge my development branch into the main branch.

It works.. but...Is anybody aware of a less clumsy/annoying way of doing this?